# Ordernar elementos de una lista en base a un elmento de una lista anidada

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

No se si he redactado bien el título, pero intentaré ser lo más claro posible. A travez de una serie de procesos y consultas llego a construir la siguiente lista:

```
asgs = [["Dep. Contaduría","Viernes","11:00"],\
        ["Dep. Papelería","Lunes","10:00"],
        ["Dep. RRHH","Martes","8:40"],
        ["Dep. Informática","Viernes","10:00"]]
```

Lo que busco es ya sea manipular la propia lista o a la hora de mostrarla, ya sea con un ciclo for, los elementos sean ordenados según el día, es decir, Lunes, Martes Miercoles... Pero claro, esos erá solo en base a los que estén en el arreglo, por ejemplo si no hay martes que pase a miercoles y así. Estuve pensando y es solo por poner un ejemplo, que sería mas facil si fueran numeros ¿No? Porque los numeros si tienen consecutividad, no como mi caso que son palabras y de alguna manera habría que decir que el primero es Lunes, el segundo es martes y así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente para ordenar los nombres de la semana necesitas un ordinal que  determine el orden. Puedes implementar un diccionario:

```
dias = {"Lunes":1, "Martes":2, "Miércoles":3, "Jueves":4, 
        "Viernes":5, "Sábado":6, "Domingo":7}
```

Y por último, podemos ordenar mediante `sorted()` de la siguiente manera:

```
lista = sorted(asgs, key=lambda x: dias[x[1]])
```

Básicamente el parámetro `key` establece una función que nos va a dar el valor que se usa para ordenar la lista, En este caso `lambda x: dias[x[1]]` es decir el número de día de cada elemento de la lista.

Importante: Revisa las cadenas del diccionario para que coincidan con las de tus datos.

La función `lambda` es una forma de declarar una función anónima, es decir una sin nombre y de un alcance muy corto, en este ejemplo solo la usamos para retornar la clave de ordenación para `sorted()`, pero puede ser más claro, hacer una función tradicional, por ejemplo, para incorporar en el orden la hora y los minutos:

```
def key_orden(x):
  dia = dias[x[1]]
  # Dividimos el 3er elemento en hora y minutos y lo llevamos a un entero
  hora, minuto = [int(e) for e in x[2].split(":")]
  # Retornamos una tupla con los tres elementos de orden
  return dia, hora, minuto

lista = sorted(asgs, key = key_orden)
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que necesitaba, lo que no termino de comprender es la funcion de **lambda x**, y otra cosa, si ya tengo el arreglo ordenado por días, si quiero ordenarlo ahora por horas pero sin perder el orden de los días, tendría que hacer otro diccionario para determinar el orden de las horas, entonces, tendría que ordenar individualmente los días, por ejemplo, si hay 3 lunes y 2 jueves tendría como que extraerlos para organizarlos individualmente y luego volver a unirlos en una lista ¿No? O algo mas o menos en ese sentido.

Comment: @Jalkhov, cheque mi última edición. Saludos.