# Ordernar elementos de una lista en base a DOS elementos de una sublista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

```
datos = [["Jhon Doe",  "Contratado", "Omega"],
         ["Joana Doe", "Jefe",       "Alfa"],
         ["Frank Doe", "Asistente",  "Beta"],
         ["Lint Doe",  "Contratado", "Beta"],
         ["Ana Doe",   "Asistente",  "Omega"],
         ["Jim Doe",   "Jefe",       "Alfa"]]

puestos = {"Jefe"       :1,
           "Contratado" :2,
           "Asistente"  :3}

rangos = {"Omega" :1,
          "Alfa"  :2,
          "Beta"  :3}
```

Buenas, tengo una lista son otras sublistas en la que cada sublista hay datos de personas con diferentes cargos y rangos, en [la siguiente pregunta (realizada por mi)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/317948/64255) he logrado ordenar los elementos de las sublistas con base en un elemento de estas, lo que no he logrado realizar es que luego de ordenar dichos elementos, hacer otra reorganización basándose en otro elemento pero sin afectar el orden realizado anteriormente, me explico mejor. En la lista de datos, cada persona tiene su puesto y su rango, cada puesto puede tener cada uno de los 3 rangos, entonces, quiera organizar la lista principalmente por los puestos y luego por su rango. Estaba pensando en realizar algún tipo de agrupación luego de la primera organización organizar cada grupo de puestos resultantes, y luego devolverlos a la lista principal, algo así, pero no se como aplicarlo.

**Básicamente busco el siguiente resultado:**

```
datos =[['Joana Doe', 'Jefe',       'Alfa'],
        ['Jim Doe',   'Jefe',       'Alfa'],
        ['Jhon Doe',  'Contratado', 'Omega'],
        ['Lint Doe',  'Contratado', 'Beta'],
        ['Ana Doe',   'Asistente',  'Omega'],
        ['Frank Doe', 'Asistente',  'Beta']]
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: El problema es apenas distinto a tu pregunta inicial, puedes hacer algo así: `datos = sorted(datos, key=lambda x: (puestos[x[1]], rangos[x[2]]))`, lo importante es llenar el parámetro `key` con los valores que usaremos para ordenar.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Vaya, jamás hubiera pensando en eso, lo que pasa es que aún estoy verde con las funciones lambda, las comprendo hasta cierto punto,me toca investigarlas mas a fondo al parecer, muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección.

Comment: @MauricioOrtega ¿Y eso no deberia hacerlo el que la contestó? Debido a que como tal no publico una respuesta no me queda de otra que votar el comentario.

Comment: Tiene razon, me equivoqué al refrenciarte pues tu hiciste la pregunta, me referia a @PMoracho. Pero también se vale contestar tu pregunta. Solo para que no quede abierta y salga en la lista como que no se ha solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la respuesta Patricio Moracho lo he resuelto de esta manera, lo coloco solo para que la pregunta no quede como no resuelta:

```
datos = sorted(datos, key=lambda x: (puestos[x[1]], rangos[x[2]]))
```